# I want to use data from one component in another component in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a simple storage app made in MEAN stack.
Now I want to use data which I display in one component (named bucket-list) also in other component (Storage).. This data is in MongoDB database..
I will share with you a little bit of code.

**bucket-list.component.ts**
[image]

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ApiService } from '../../service/api.service';
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bucket-list',
  templateUrl: './bucket-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bucket-list.component.css']
})

export class BucketListComponent implements OnInit {
  Bucket:any = [];

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { 
    this.readBucket();
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  readBucket(){
    this.apiService.getBuckets().subscribe((data) => {
     this.Bucket = data;
    })    
  }


  removeBucket(bucket:any, index:any) {
    if(window.confirm('Do you really want to delete this object?')) {
        this.apiService.deleteBucket(bucket._id).subscribe((data) => {
          this.Bucket.splice(index, 1);
        }
      )    
    }
  } 
}
```

**bucket-list.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
<br>
<p *ngIf="Bucket.length <= 0" class="no-data text-center">There is no Buckets added yet!</p>
<h3 class="left">All buckets ({{Bucket.length}})</h3>
<div class="btn btn-primary right">
<a class="teksta" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/create-bucket">Create new bucket</a>
</div>
<!-- Employee list -->
<table class="table table-border" *ngIf="Bucket.length > 0">
  <thead class="table">
    <tr>
      <!--<th scope="col">Bucket ID</th>-->
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Location</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let bucket of Bucket; let i = index">
      <!--<th scope="row">{{bucket._id}}</th>-->
      <td routerLink="/storage" class="klikni">{{bucket.name}}</td>
      <td>{{bucket.location}}</td>

      <td class="text-center">
        <span class="delete" (click)="removeBucket(bucket, i)">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**storage.component.ts**
[image]
Here, below upload button I want to display same table as in bucket-list.component.html (with alittle bit different "front-end")

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
import { ApiService } from './../../service/api.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-storage',
  templateUrl: './storage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./storage.component.css']
})

export class StorageComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedFile: File;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private apiService: ApiService) { this.readBucket(); }

  onFileSelected(event:any){
    this.selectedFile = <File>event.target.files[0];
    console.log(event);
  }

  onUpload(){
    const file = new FormData();


    file.append('image', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
    this.http.post('url_od_cloud_storage', file)
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
      });
  }
  ngOnInit() {}


**//this is data from the bucket-list.component.ts**
  Bucket:any = [];

  readBucket(){
    this.apiService.getBuckets().subscribe((data) => {
     this.Bucket = data;
    })    
  }

  removeBucket(bucket:any, index:any) {
    if(window.confirm('Do you really want to delete this object?')) {
        this.apiService.deleteBucket(bucket._id).subscribe((data) => {
          this.Bucket.splice(index, 1);
        }
      )    
    }
  } 
}
```

**storage-component.html**

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <h3 class="left" style="margin-left: 25%; margin-top: 20px;">MyNewStorage</h3>
  <div class="col-md-4 register-employee">
        <br><br>
        <h4>Upload an image to cloud storage!</h4>
        <input type="file" (change)="onFileSelected($event)">
        <br><br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onUpload()">Upload         Object</button>
      </div>
</div>

<p *ngIf="Bucket.length <= 0" class="no-data text-center">There is no Buckets added yet!</p>
    <h3 class="left">All buckets ({{Bucket.length}})</h3>
    <div class="btn btn-primary right">
    <a class="teksta" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/create-bucket">Create new bucket</a>
    </div>
<!-- Employee list -->
<table class="table table-border">
  <thead class="table">
    <tr>
      <!--<th scope="col">Bucket ID</th>-->
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Location</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let bucket of Bucket; let i = index">
      <th scope="row">{{bucket._id}}</th>
      <td routerLink="/storage" class="klikni">{{bucket.name}}</td>
      <td>{{bucket.location}}</td>

      <td class="text-center">
        <span class="delete" (click)="removeBucket(bucket, i)">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You'll want to look into `Services`, a great way to share data between components, ie https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

Comment: Is this an only option? Or I can just make this easier with my existing code and existing components?